# Mute user that i have replayed with telebot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am using pytelegrambotapi, and this code

```
def mute(message):
bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time()+86400)
```

But it doesn't mute person i reply, what should i do?